# NiFi ListHDFS cannot find directory, FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-nifi

Have pipeline in NiFi of the form `listHDFS->moveHDFS`, attempting to run the pipeline we see the error log

```
13:29:21 HSTDEBUG01631000-d439-1c41-9715-e0601d3b971c
ListHDFS[id=01631000-d439-1c41-9715-e0601d3b971c] Returning CLUSTER State: StandardStateMap[version=43, values={emitted.timestamp=1525468790000, listing.timestamp=1525468790000}]
13:29:21 HSTDEBUG01631000-d439-1c41-9715-e0601d3b971c
ListHDFS[id=01631000-d439-1c41-9715-e0601d3b971c] Found new-style state stored, latesting timestamp emitted = 1525468790000, latest listed = 1525468790000
13:29:21 HSTDEBUG01631000-d439-1c41-9715-e0601d3b971c
ListHDFS[id=01631000-d439-1c41-9715-e0601d3b971c] Fetching listing for /hdfs/path/to/dir
13:29:21 HSTERROR01631000-d439-1c41-9715-e0601d3b971c
ListHDFS[id=01631000-d439-1c41-9715-e0601d3b971c] Failed to perform listing of HDFS due to File /hdfs/path/to/dir does not exist: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /hdfs/path/to/dir does not exist
```

Changing the listHDFS path to /tmp seems to run ok, thus making me think that the problem is with my permissions on the directory I'm trying to list. However, changing the NiFi user to a user that can access that directory (eg. `hadoop fs -ls /hdfs/path/to/dir`) by setting the `bootstrap.properties` value `run.as=myuser` and restarting (see https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#bootstrap_properties) still seems to produce the same problem for the directory. The literal dir. string being used that is not working is:

> "/etl/ucera_internal/datagov_example/raw-ingest-tracking/version-1/ingest"

Does anyone know what is happening here? Thanks.

** Note: The hadoop cluster I am accessing does not have kerberos enabled (it is a secured `MapR` hadoop cluster).

**Update**: It appears that the `mapr` hadoop implementation is different enough that it requires special steps in order for NiFi to properly work on it (see https://community.mapr.com/thread/10484 and http://hariology.com/integrating-mapr-fs-and-apache-nifi/). May not get a chance to work on this problem for some time to see if still works (as certain requirements have changed), so am dumping the link here for others who may have this problem in the meantime.

Comment: I would suggest changing the permissions on the HDFS directory to include the `nifi` user rather than changing the NiFi run.as user because a number of other conditions depend on the OS user NiFi is running under.

Comment: A quick question. Are you using the correct `core-site.xml` & `hdfs-site.xml`? Can you check the files when you use `/tmp` is the same when you check using `hdfs dfs -ls /tmp` ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you once make sure you have entered correct path and **directory** needs to be exists in HDFS.

It seems to be **list hdfs processor** not able to **find the directory** that you have configured in directory property and logs are not showing any permission denied issues.

If logs shows permission denied then you can change the nifi running user in bootstrap.conf and 
Once you make change in nifi properties then NiFi needs to restart to apply the changes **(or)** change the permissions on the directory that NiFi can have access.

Comment: Yes, the path is correct (using same path, can successfully run a `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/dir` command). Only reason thought to try changing permissions was because it seemed weird that I could not list even though the path woks in the console (and new to NiFi, so was not sure what exactly the FileNotExists error exactly implied), but the only logs I actually see are the ones posted (they just repeat).

Comment: FileNotExists error means when we are trying to access directory that doesn't exists in HDFS processor will throws FileNotExists error.
For testing purpose use GetHDFS processor with same directory and change the **Keep sourcefile property** to true

Comment: Testing with the getHDFS processor, I get a similar `WARNING` error of `GetHDFS[id=2de35272-0163-1000-738d-766b47f6d3f0] The directory /hdfs/path/to/dir does not exist`. Yet cutting and pasting that dir. string into the command `hadoop fs -ls <paste here>` still works. Even tried using a glob pattern in the dir. string for the processor (ie. /hdfs/path/to/dir/*) and still did not work. This is very strange.

Comment: Could you once check is there any **space's before/after or newline** your directory value?
because if you are having spaces still **hadoop fs -ls command** works and shows the files

Comment: Yes, there are no spaces on either ends of the string, which is literally "/etl/ucera_internal/datagov_example/raw-ingest-tracking/version-1/ingest". Thanks for the debugging checks though, I know this is a weird problem.